# Oracle: Modify primary/foreignkeys and constrains inside a TRIGGER

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, constraints

we have an issue with the folowing trigger where we have to disable certain constraints to add the primary key of a table:

```
    create or replace trigger TRG_NAMENSAENDERUNG_MA
      after update of vname, nname on mitarbeiter
      referencing new as new old as old
      for each row
    declare
      initialien char(2);
      benutzernr int;
      benutzername_neu char(5);
      benutzername_alt char(5);
    begin

/*...
Code sets corect values to all variables.
...*/

/* the following is suposed to disable the two constraints*/
for i in (select fk_session_log_ben_name, SESSION_LOGGING FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS) loop
        execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE'||i.session_logging||' DISABLE CONSTRAINT '||i.fk_session_log_ben_name||'';
      end loop;

      for i in (select fk_geraetekto_ben_name, GERAETEKONTO FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS) loop
        execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE'||i.geraetekonto||' DISABLE CONSTRAINT '||i.fk_geraetekto_ben_name||'';
      end loop;

/*Update statements which can only work without the constraints!!: */

      UPDATE BENUTZERKONTO SET BENUTZERNAME = benutzername_neu WHERE BENUTZERNAME = benutzername_alt;
      UPDATE SESSION_LOGGING SET BENUTZERNAME = benutzername_neu WHERE BENUTZERNAME = benutzername_alt;
      UPDATE GERAETEKONTO SET BENUTZERNAME = benutzername_neu WHERE BENUTZERNAME = benutzername_alt;


/*Supposed to re-enable the constraints. */
      for i in (select fk_session_log_ben_name, SESSION_LOGGING FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS) loop
        execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE'||i.session_logging||' ENABLE CONSTRAINT '||i.fk_session_log_ben_name||'';
      end loop;

      for i in (select fk_geraetekto_ben_name, GERAETEKONTO FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS) loop
        execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE'||i.geraetekonto||' ENABLE CONSTRAINT '||i.fk_geraetekto_ben_name||'';
      end loop;
    end TRG_NAMENSAENDERUNG_MA;
```

It throws the error that SESSION_LOGGING would be an "invalid identifier". It is typed right though and we copied the syntax from the example from the Oracale page.

What's the easiest way to achieve what we want?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't want to be performing DDL in a trigger if you can avoid it... I know this doesn't answer the question but you might be better served by stating what you're actually trying to achieve. You could also use deferable constraints instead.

Comment: Well, we just have a database meant for a small company. The table "benutzerkonto" holds the users in the company. Now a user has changed his real name and therefore changes its "benutzername" (username, which is a primary key).
This requires to alter his name (benutzername) in multiple other tables (gerätekonto and session_logging) too where "benutzername" is a foreign key.
How would I achive that without disabling the constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first suggestion is to redesign the schema so that it's no need to change the PK values (especially by users). PK must be surrogate. There must be serious reasons for a decision like yours. Hope you don't need such reasons :) The redesign mentioned, methinks, would be less expensive than struggling with the problem you cast. With changing PK values you'll probably face such problems again and again as the application is evolved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Well, I have explained just over you (in the other comment) why this task is sort of necessarily... It would be the only case where such a variable has to be changed.

What I wonder the most - why doesn't disabling the constraint work?

Comment: Your code looks really strange to me: Why do you need to set a cursor loop? Why don't you use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE without LOOP? And as jonearles told `SESSION_LOGGING` is neither the table column nor a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the invalid identifier, these columns do not exist in `USER_CONSTRAINTS`.  The full error message should have included the line number and given a hint at the meaning.

```
select fk_session_log_ben_name, SESSION_LOGGING FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
```

The code should probably be this:

```
select constraint_name fk_session_log_ben_name, table_name SESSION_LOGGING
FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS;
```